# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus driver for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, usb

I am looking for a driver for the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus, on Uubuntu 20.04 (kernel version 5.11.0-40-generic).

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter

$ inxi -N | grep "TP-Link"
  Device-2: TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: usb-network
```

I installed a driver and it worked for the first time, when I opened the coputer today, the adaptater doesn't give me any Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Install the driver again. If you didn't use dkms, you need to install it after each kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

I resolve it. I reinstalled the driver with this commands:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

If you don't hace permission try to execute:

```
chmod 777 rtl8812au
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as op and using `chmod 777 rtl8812au` command didn't help. The connection is wiped out after i restart my computer. Also I can't connect to the 5Ghz band. How to connect to 5Ghz with T2U plus?

Comment: I had to fight a lot to find a usefull solution and a found some that I don't remeber. The last one I did was starting the process from 0. I mean to remove dkms and git and then follow the same commands again. Try with sudo apt remove dkms git.

Comment: How to verify that this solution worked, other than of course that device starts working?