# How to reinstall or fix a broken usb (wifi) driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

In the past I used the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376835/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-plus-driver-for-ubuntu-20-04) to install a driver for my tplink t2u usb driver. This worked fine for quite some time, even when updating ubuntu from version 20.04 to 22.04.

However right now when I start (and reboot multiple times) my computer it says "no wifi adapter found". - The antenna is still working as booting into windows shows it working.

When I list the usb devices it is also found

```
$lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
```

I tried to just run the install again, however that resulted into the error:

```
$ sudo make dkms_install
cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
dkms add -m 8812au -v 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
Error! DKMS tree already contains: 8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
make: *** [Makefile:2303: dkms_install] Error 3
```

Which seems to indicate the driver is still "there"  just not working? How can I fix this?

For completeness the full release information of my desktop system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


$ uname -a
Linux paul-desktop 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

I've uninstalled the current driver as I noticed that the driver worked for a different kernel version

```
$ dkms status
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Then reinstalling gave the following error:

```
$ sudo make dkms_install
cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
dkms add -m 8812au -v 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/source -> /usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
dkms build -m 8812au -v 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j16 KVER=5.19.0-32-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8812au: 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.19.0-32-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information.
make: *** [Makefile:2304: dkms_install] Error 10
```

The specific driver checks gave:

```
$ sudo modprobe 88XXau
modprobe: FATAL: Module 88XXau not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i 88XX
$
```

Comment: You've not said which kernel stack you're using; the 20.04 HWE & 22.04 GA stack were identical (*thus same results can be expected*) but are you using HWE thus 5.15 recently changed to 5.19?  (*reverting to GA kernels tack may fix if you don't find other solution for HWE kernel stack*)  *You didn't say if you're using a server or desktop system, which have different kernel stack defaults...*

Comment: @guiverc sorry you are now asking beyond my knowledge, how  do I know which kernel stack (and would it have been updated in a standard update last friday?). I think I don't run a server system - at least I shouldn't.

Comment: You mention releases; but didn't state what product (ie. Server which defaults to the *older & more stable* GA kernel stack, or Desktop which defaults to the HWE or *newer* stack better for newer video cards etc).   `uname -r` at terminal will tell you the kernel in use; only first two numbers matter (eg. on my box I get `6.1.0-16-generic` so it's 6.1 that matters; 5.15 is the GA stack for 22.04, 5.19 indicates HWE stack for 22.04, OEM can be something else...) ... 22.04.2 only recently rolled out meaning 5.15 changed to 5.19 for those using it...

Comment: @guiverc added the release information. It is indeed 5.19 - how can I revert and is that a "safe"  operation that wouldn't break other things?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo modprobe 88XXau` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i 88XX`

Comment: @chili555 added the information

Comment: Please see above: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information." Let's see what it says: `cat /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log`