# Wine to install Archer T2U Plus Driver (for Windows) in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, wine, tp-link

I have an Archer T2U Plus WiFi Adapter. After purchasing I came to know that it only supports Windows and macOS and I want to run it on my Xubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I had searched regarding this thing on Stackoverflow, GitHub, AskUbuntu and various other StackExchange websites. They suggested to install various git software:

[Archer-T2U-Plus-Driver on Github](https://github.com/nlkguy/archer-t2u-plus-linux),
[Discussion on TP-Link](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/184118),
[Community Discussion on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376835/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-plus-driver-for-ubuntu-20-04)

But none of the above works on my Xubuntu. All of them stops on 8188au.ko installation. No matter how many times I tried that. It didn't install any driver to get this Archer WiFi adapter get running.

---

I was finding any workarounds and I decided to try wine to install driver.

I had used Wine Emulator on Xubuntu to install GTA Vice City game and it did install. So I downloaded the Archer T2U Plus Driver for Windows 7 (I set default Windows version to Windows 7 on wine) from its [official website](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t2u-plus/).

And I tried to run the Setup.exe file from the extracted folder and it keeps saying that 'Setup file cannot find the WiFi adapter'. Is it an issue with Wine or the .exe file is not compatible with wine.

Another Question is: If wine is able to install 'gta-vc-setup.exe' without any issue, then why it cannot do the same with the Adapter's setup file ?

Comment: wine is not a hardware layer so it will never work.  If you can not get it to work using the link in your 1st link buy another wifi adapter.  You did not mention the device id but it should be 2357:0120 If so https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708 --works-- You just need to follow the instruction. alternatively: make a log and file a bug in the wiki on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Is it an issue with Wine or the .exe file is not compatible with wine.*"

Wine cannot install any kind of driver. Wine cannot control your hardware in that way.

A Windows driver won't work on a Linux kernel anyway.